# Is dispatch_once overkill inside of +[NSObject initialize]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-runtime

If I create a singleton inside of `+[NSObject initialize]`, do I need to put my code inside a `dispatch_once` block like so?

```
static NSObject * Bar;
@implementation Foo
+ (void)initialize {
  if (self == [Foo class]) {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      Bar = [NSObject new];
    });
  }
}
@end
```

**EDIT**

I'm concerned about this because I want to make sure that all threads will see that I've set `Bar` after `+[Foo initialize]` is called. The documentation says `+[NSObject initialize]` is thread-safe, but does that imply it is memory-safe?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping your logic to **only** needing the `dispatch_once()` and just use that.   It is more straightforward and copy/paste during a refactoring of the code won't break it.

Comment: I agree. That's what I do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bill Bumgarner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum) says that [`dispatch_once` is Apple's recommended practice now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14125791/9636).

Relating to thread and memory-safety of `+initialize`, thanks to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/eridius/status/444228009675849729), I found the [relevant runtime sources](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime) to check. `objc-initialize.mm` says:

```
 * Only one thread is allowed to actually initialize a class and send 
 * +initialize. Enforced by allowing only one thread to set CLS_INITIALIZING.
```

Classes may be initialized on different threads, and `objc-initialize.mm` has a strategy to avoid them deadlocking:

```
*  +initialize deadlock case when a class is marked initializing while 
 *  its superclass is initialized. Solved by completely initializing 
 *  superclasses before beginning to initialize a class.
 *
 *  OmniWeb class hierarchy:
 *                 OBObject 
 *                     |    ` OBPostLoader
 *                 OFObject
 *                 /     \
 *      OWAddressEntry  OWController
 *                        | 
 *                      OWConsoleController
 *
 *  Thread 1 (evil testing thread):
 *    initialize OWAddressEntry
 *    super init OFObject
 *    super init OBObject            
 *    [OBObject initialize] runs OBPostLoader, which inits lots of classes...
 *    initialize OWConsoleController
 *    super init OWController - wait for Thread 2 to finish OWController init
 *
 *  Thread 2 (normal OmniWeb thread):
 *    initialize OWController
 *    super init OFObject - wait for Thread 1 to finish OFObject init
 *
 *  deadlock!
 *
 *  Solution: fully initialize super classes before beginning to initialize 
 *  a subclass. Then the initializing+initialized part of the class hierarchy
 *  will be a contiguous subtree starting at the root, so other threads 
 *  can't jump into the middle between two initializing classes, and we won't 
 *  get stuck while a superclass waits for its subclass which waits for the 
 *  superclass.
```

Additionally, class initialization state variables, are guarded by a `monitor_t`, [which is actually defined as](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-os.h):

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
} monitor_t;
```

Since it is a `p_thread_mutex`, and [p_thread calls implement memory barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208140/9636), it is equally safe to use:

```
static NSObject * Bar;
@implementation Foo
+ (void)initialize {
  if (self == [Foo class]) {
    Bar = [NSObject new];
  }
}
@end
```

and

```
static NSObject * Bar;
@implementation Foo
+ (void)initialize {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    Bar = [NSObject new];
  });
}
@end
```

Comment: Because of everything you listed, it is undoubtedly fastest just to say `+ (void)initialize { static BOOL initialized = NO; if (!initialized) { /* initialize here */ initialized = YES; } }`

Comment: Also, micro-benchmarking performed on armv7s and arm64 indicates that `if (self == [Foo class])` outperforms `dispatch_once()`, but the difference is <100ns. Also, trying to micro-optimize here is rather pointless. So my overall suggestion is use whichever of the 3 approaches you find most readable.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your direct question is that you don't need the `dispatch_once`, but you *do* need the class check that you have in there, because `+initialize` will be called [once per "non-implementing subclass" as well](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/). It will only be called once for the specific class you care about (`Foo`), so the `dispatch_once` is extraneous. Re: thread safety, the `+initialize` method will complete before any other methods are dispatched to the class (or its instances).

However, you don't describe the desired access pattern, so depending on what you want, you may wish to do the opposite-- if you expect subclasses to have access to `Bar`, too, then this would be fragile; if the subclass gets initialized before `Foo` itself is, then the class check will prevent `Bar` from being created. If you intend this behavior, then use the `dispatch_once` but remove the class check-- that will generally allow `Bar` to be created the first time `Foo` or any of its subclasses are initialized. (Caveat: unless a subclass [also overrides `+initialize`, of course](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html).)

Comment: I would actually prefer checking `if (Bar == nil)` rather than `self == [Foo class]`, but I think that boils down to style.

Comment: `self == [Foo class]` is a correct pattern for all uses of `+initialize`. Checking something else, like `Bar==nil` is a special case that applies to this code, but is not a general pattern. I would recommend the standard class check.

Comment: But what about memory safety? Are all threads guaranteed to see the change to Bar that +[Foo initialize] made?

Comment: @HeathBorders: Yes, but it sounds like there's another nuanced behavior here, especially around subclassing. I updated the answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) mention the `initialize` method is only called once per class in a thread-safe manner. Therefore `dispatch_once` is not necessary.

> The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program exactly one
>   time just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is
>   sent its first message from within the program. (Thus the method may
>   never be invoked if the class is not used.) The runtime sends the
>   initialize message to classes in a thread-safe manner. Superclasses
>   receive this message before their subclasses.

**EDIT**

As @Vincent Gable mentions in the comments, the `initialize` method may be called more than once if a subclass of `Foo` does not implement `initialize` method itself. However, such calls won't be a problem because there is a `self == [Foo class]` check.

Comment: Not quite, +initialize can happen more than once sometimes "…if a subclass does not implement +initialize but its superclass does, then that superclass’s +initialize will be invoked once per non-implementing subclass and once for itself." http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/

Comment: But what about memory safety? Are all threads guaranteed to see the change to `Bar` that `+[Foo initialize]` made?

Comment: Per the docs: "The runtime sends `initialize` to each class in a program exactly one time just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program." Taking the most paranoid interpretation, I could see how all threads might *not* see the change to the global `Bar` before reading it. An easy solution would be to move `Bar` from being a global to being a singleton accessed via a method -- that way a message would have to be sent to access it, guaranteeing that it will have been initialized before anyone can read it.