# soundcloud API can't find file "SCTAppDelegate.m"

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am following the instructions for the [SoundCloud iOS SDK](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart). I have downloaded all the necessary files already and added them to my project's workspace.

However, at one point, this instruction comes up:

> Now that we've got our project created and dependencies installed, it's time to write some code. The first thing you'll need to do is set your client credentials. This is done by calling a method on the `SCSoundCloud` class. It's easiest to do this in the initialize class method in your app delegate, so open up `SCTAppDelegate.m` and add this near the top, underneath the `@implementation SCTAppDelegate` line:

The problem is that I can't find `SCTAppDelegate.m`. Is it that I have missed downloading that file somewhere? Or is it because I am currently using `Xcode 6/Swift` and that file is not relevant/doesn't exist anymore (in that case would it be somewhere else?).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Kevin, did my answer ever help?  Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

`SCTAppDelegate.m` represents the AppDelegate in your sample application.  In your case, use your `AppDelegate.swift` file.

Comment: Alright, and It presume the initialize function is now the view did load function?

Comment: @west123 no, every class has an initialize function: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize.  Note that this class uses the Objective-C runtime.  For native Swift classes, check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137212/initialize-class-method-for-classes-in-swift.